# My record field name clashes with other record fields in the same scope

Tags: haskell

I have create the following data type :

```
data IntroduceIdea = IntroduceIdea { id :: UUID , userId ::UUID , createdOn :: UTCTime,
                                 ideaContent :: String } deriving (Eq,Show)
```

I have clashes with the prelude (with the id field)... so I have added the extension `{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}` but it feels wrong to me to paste it everywhere I use it...do you have better solution ?

Comment: Why not rename it to `introduceIdeaId`?

Comment: it adds a lot of verbosity for nothing don't you think ?

Comment: introduceIdeaId introduceIdea instead of id introduceIdea

Comment: then I don't understand why it clashes when it's applied to a specific type.

Comment: Because you introduce two (or more) `id` functions, toogether with the `id` function of the *prelude*. The one has a `a -> a` signature, the other a `IntroduceIdea -> UUID`

Comment: can't we have 2 functions with the same name but with a different signatures ?

Comment: by default, no, since that would result in ambiguty. You can solve this by using a typeclass, like `f :: Foo x => x -> Int` for example. This is more or less how you can *emulate* the `DuplicateRecordFields`: for every property you define a typeclass, like `class Idable a where id :: a -> UUID`, or even `class Idable a b where id :: a -> b`

Comment: Functions don't have names; rather, you can bind one or more names *to* an otherwise anonymous function. The name itself just refers to *a* value, with no information about what that value is stored with the name.

Comment: Language extensions are commonly used; don't feel bad about having lots of them. (There are jokes about a module being a toy example unless the extension list is longer than the actual code.) With any luck, the next Haskell standard will include many of the GHC-contributed extensions, letting you drop those pragmas.

Answer (score 2):

Willem Van Onsem's suggestion of naming it `introduceIdeaId` seems to me the most idiomatic solution. This took me some time to get used to, coming from C# and F#, where objects and records are typically made up from class fields or record properties.

In such languages, you can't really refer to such fields or properties without the record to which they're attached, so 'repeating' the name of the 'object' in the name of the field seems redundant.

In Haskell, data records are made up of a collection of *functions*. Specifically, that label would be this function:

```
> :t introduceIdeaId
introduceIdeaId :: IntroduceIdea -> UUID
```

It's a function that takes an `IntroduceIdea` value as input, and returns a `UUID` as output.

That data labels are 'real' functions can be useful when composing functions. For example, if you have a (small) list of `IntroduceIdea` values (`x` and `y`), you can extract the `introduceIdeaId` labels and turn them into `String` values in point-free style:

```
> fmap (show . introduceIdeaId) [x, y]
["c44a4cb1-f494-46b5-9459-9a022d364bfa","f3de5def-0bad-46a7-b3a2-604c7ecd54e6"]
```

Here, `introduceIdeaId` is used as the function that it is. The name has to be unambiguous. Had we used the name `id`, it wouldn't have been clear if we meant `IntroduceIdea -> UUID` or `a -> a`.

Comment: can I get something more flexible by using the libray Lens ? I'm reading about it now...

Comment: @NicolasHenin I don't *think* so; lenses aren't my forte, so I could be wrong, but I think that lenses need to have unique names as well.

Comment: `One of Haskell’s most egregious shortcomings is that you can’t use the same field name in different record types. I’ll explain how we are planning to fix that (joint work with Adam Gundry), and how the result will fit nicely into the lens world.` https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/4251-lenses-compositional-data-access-and-manipulation

Comment: I don't have a concrete example about how but I'm still searching about it :-)

Comment: @NicolasHenin Lens won't allow you to create record fields with the same name, but it'll allow you to create _lenses_ with the same name that can refer to similar fields in different types of records.